# Javascript – determine number of elements need to be removed or added

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, dom

I know there's a simple solution for this problem but I've trying to solve this for quite some time already and need your help.

In my code I'm reordering my article DIV's based on screen width, and wrapping them into rows and inserting dummy articles if needed.

Now, let's say I have a jQuery set of 4 article DIV's and 1 dummy. I then need to know if I really need to insert more dummies or remove some. The correct number of articles per row is passed to the function in question. For example, let's say there needs to be 2 articles per row.

So, before I run the code the layout looks like this:

```
| Article | Article |
| Article | Article |
|  Dummy  |
```

... when it need to be like this ( redundant dummies removed ):

```
| Article | Article |
| Article | Article |
```

This is my current code:

```
var checkForDummies     = function ( unwrappedArticles, articlesPerRow ) {

        var $articles       = $( unwrappedArticles ),
            len             = $articles.length,
            i,
            dummiesFound    = $articles.filter( '.dummy-cell' ),
            dummiesNeeded   = (len - dummiesFound.length) % articlesPerRow,
            fragment        = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            div             = document.createElement( 'div' );

        // No dummies needed after removal    
        if      ( dummiesNeeded === 0 && dummiesFound.length )
            dummiesFound.remove();
        // No dummies needed nor found
        else if ( dummiesNeeded === 0 )
            return;
        // Dummies needed – remove redundant dummies ( max. dummies needed = dummiesNeeded )
        else if ( dummiesNeeded < dummiesFound.length )
            dummiesFound.splice( dummiesNeeded );
        // Dummies needed – create new ones
        else if ( dummiesNeeded > dummiesFound.length )
            // Left out to preserve space

    };
```

However, this code will not work when the layout looks like this (5 articles per row) – because the `dummiesNeeded` is somehow `1` instead of `4`:

```
| Article | Article | Article | Article | Article |
| Article |  Dummy  |
```

Any help to find a solution for this is appreciated! Thanks!

**Updated solution**
With help of the marked answer, I needed to modify the `dummiesNeeded` and insert a new variable that hold signed integer of dummies needed:

```
dummiesNeeded   = (articlesPerRow - (len - dummiesFound.length) % articlesPerRow) % articlesPerRow,
trueNeed        = dummiesNeeded - dummiesFound.length
```

Comment: So is this function called once *per row*? Or is it supposed to be called once for the whole set?

Comment: @MattBurland it's called only once per set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to layout a table of contents on a fixed-sized page (multi-column)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524699/algorithm-to-layout-a-table-of-contents-on-a-fixed-sized-page-multi-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
dummiesNeeded   = (len - dummiesFound.length) % articlesPerRow
```

If, as in your example, you have one article (so len = 1) and one dummy (so dummiesFound.length = 1), then 1-1 = 0, so your `dummiesNeeded` ends up being 0. 0 % 5 = 0 instead of the 4 you wanted.

Surely your `dummiesNeeded` should be:

```
dummiesNeeded = (articlePerRow - (len - dummiesFound.length) % articlesPerRow) % articlesPerRow;
```

Comment: I think `len` is actually the total number of articles in this function. (7 in the second example). Although it feels overly complex, the formula `(articlesPerRow - (len % articlesPerRow) + dummiesFound.length) % articlesPerRow` seems to work.

Comment: @ElliotNelson: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. It wasn't clear whether this is called per row, or on the whole set (hence my question above). However, I'm not sure why the OP is bothering with `dummiesFound` anyway. Are they included in `len` already? It's not clear at all.

Comment: @ElliotNelson That is correct – `len` includes the dummy elements as well. I could have remove all dummies first, and create them again. But that would make some unnecessary DOM manipulation

Comment: @MattBurland That's because I want to know if I have to splice the dummy-set or add new ones. Any performance tips are also more than welcome if you have any. :D

Comment: @micadelli: Yeah, I just noticed that you are filtering your articles to get your dummies.

Comment: @micadelli: Is it possible that you'll have a whole row of dummies?

Comment: @MattBurland That could be possible in some rare cases, and that's why I spliced the set to have a maximum of dummies needed.

Comment: @MattBurland Hmmm... that new `dummiesNeeded` would be 2 in this example, `dummiesNeeded = 2 - (3 - 1) % 2` when it should be -1 (or 0, depending on how the removal of redundant dummies are implemented)

Comment: @micadelli: It has a problem when you run it on already completed rows. I think another mod 2 will fix it. So `dummiesNeeded = (2 - (3 - 1) % 2) % 2`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed
`(len - dummiesFound.length) % articlesPerRow`

you have to use `articlesPerRow - ((len - dummiesFound.length) % articlesPerRow)`

Cheers

Comment: Same as Matt's answer, that would be `2`, when `len = 3`, `dummiesFound = 1` and `perRow = 2` when it should be `-1 (or 0)`